# Possible to embed TV signal in an Android TV app?

Tags: android, android-tv, smart-tv

On Samsung Tizen TVs there's an API called [TVWindow](http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/api-references/tizen-web-device-api-references/tvwindow-api) which allows for displaying the live TV signal (either terrestrial or from an HDMI input such as Foxtel) within an application.

Is there an equivalent library for Android TV? So far I haven't been able to find one.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [TV Input Framework](https://source.android.com/devices/tv/). It says:

> Third-party TV inputs can either display their own content or content from a device manufacturer’s passthrough TV inputs, like HDMI1. They can’t display content from non-passthrough TV inputs, like a built-in or IPTV tuner.

So depending on your use-case, you could use the TV Input Manager to get access to the HDMI TV Input provided by the device manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks! I really need a way to get input from the built-in tuner, is that not possible?

Comment: Can you please specify your use-case?

Comment: Are you saying that you want a television to send the picture it is receiving over the air to an Android TV and then have the Android TV overlay something on it to send back to the television to display?

Comment: At the company I work for we have developed an app for the elderly that allows them to use their TV as normal but displays additional information around the edge of the TV, as well as popup notifications/reminders. Currently we have the app running on Samsung Tizen TVs and another popular TV brand. We're aiming to port our app onto a third brand of TV, and they use Android TV as their TV's OS.

In this case Android TV will be running on the TV itself, not a separate device, so I don't think it's necessary to send the signal and then send it back or anything.

Comment: Then I think you have to use the HDMI input. At least I don't know another way to get the signal. But you could just try and see what happens if you try to access the tuner TV Input via the TV Input Manager. Maybe rooting is an option as well, but I honestly don't think, that there are a lot of examples unfortunately.